# how to run asp .net project using lan connection through IP

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, ip, lan

I am using asp.net .. i have created one small application.. I have Configure my application in IIS 7 and if I am running in my system through ip am able to run.. but same thing if am running in LAN network using ip of my system.. **I am getting the following error(The server at 192.168.1.11 is taking too long to respond.)**.

Comment: did you check your firewall settings? it should be off.

Comment: Do you have a firewall running on the host machine?

Comment: Yes Done with firewall settings. thanks @Furqan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Off firewall setting it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a rule for IIS in the Windows firewall?